# How to verify .iso from https://www.ubuntu.com (Official Site) from OS X mac

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, mac, iso, macosx

A barrage of verification questions:

The only other question I saw was regarding a torrented `.iso`. I got mine from https://www.ubuntu.com (Official Site)

My questions:

1. Do I need truly need verify if it is from the official site? What's the risk?
2. Don't have `gpg` command on a mac; can I skip this step?
3. Did a 256 checksum of my `.iso` and it did not match the one hosted @ https://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify... What!? - Re-Downloading to double check...

**UPDATE / SOLVED**:

This time my SHA256 and GPG verification came out clean.

Here's what I learned:

Download the SHA256 files, don't just copy and paste into a new text file (this will corrupt the output of `gpg`).

I used `curl -O  http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/SHA256SUMS` to download via terminal.

All you need is the `SHA256SUMS` AND `SHA256SUMS.gpg` not MD5 and SHA1 etc.

Then follow the steps outlined here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify (and below if you don't have `gpg` installed on mac get homebrew package manager and run `brew install gnupg`

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I need truly need verify if it is from the official site? What's the risk?

Well, dunno if you noticed, but http://releases.ubuntu.com/ isn't HTTPS. You could have easily downloaded from an impersonating webpage. However, using PGP signing lets you verify that the file is correct and from the Ubuntu team.

> Don't have gpg command on a mac; can I skip this step?

Homebrew it: http://brewformulas.org/Gnupg. What's life on a Mac without homebrew or the like?

> Did a 256 checksum of my .iso and it did not match the one hosted ...

Can't really say - was the file completely downloaded? Did it get corrupted somehow?

Note that Ubuntu offers official torrents - consider downloading using those for reliability.

Comment: Isn't the signature on HTTP as well? http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Comment: Yes, but they cannot fake the private key used to sign the signature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! `brew install` super helpful

Comment: OS X without homebrew is like life without Stack Exchange - absolutely hopeless!

Comment: @ChrisCirefice I like homebrew. The thing that gets me about package managers, is how do I trust the repository? I understand for `apt-get` it is checked by human eyes; it seems like you could easily sneak in malware or some garbage and I've always been curious on how to protect from that, or how the admins of the repository protect from that

Comment: @KolobCanyon whom are you talking about trusting? Linux package maintainers or homebrew package maintainers?

Comment: @KolobCanyon It seems to me that the 'standard' packages (defaulty 'included' in homebrew) are actually [Ruby scripts in the homebrew core Git repo](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/tree/master/Formula). Since it's open-source, it is reviewed by the collaborators on the repo before being included, and it's entirely public so sneaking things in would be hard. However, software maintainers can just as easily write scripts to work with Homebrew that *aren't* in that repo, but you (the user) would have to *manually* invoke the custom script to install.

Comment: @muru Asking the question about all package managers, but I know `homebrew` and `apt-get` are two separate entities. I assume `apt-get` is Canonical and Christ said `homebrew` is open source

Comment: @KolobCanyon apt-get is also open source (it comes from Debian). Well, you can trust either about as much as you trust any software vendor - you can examine the code used for packaging for every package in Ubuntu, just like you can with homebrew, but how do you know that's what's actually used at the server that builds the package? You don't, so unless you fancy building all those packages yourself, I suppose you can trust them.

Comment: @muru Really shows how much trust we put into these kind of things.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to the question asked:

1. Do I need truly need verify if it is from the official site? What's the risk?

   - You need to do this so you don't get a copy that has been altered to give *some one or some organization* access to your system and hence information
2. Don't have gpg command on a mac; can I skip this step?

   - Yes you can, use the *alternative* listed instead
3. Did a 256 checksum of my .iso and it did not match the one hosted @ https://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify... What!? - Re-Downloading to double check...

   - Please checked that you followed the instructions there to the latter, and besides they are many other factors that could have caused this. But after this if your still not *okay* then I guess *support* should come in handy.

Comment: I guess I should have asked, can I *safely* skip that step?

Comment: +1 anyway, helpful to me as well

Comment: @KolobCanyon I guess if it's broken they always say to compare the checksum. I never have...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I hardly check myself as I usually verify the site via the `https` and or site online rep.

Comment: @George I'm just lazy and don't really care about virus, malware and the NSA :)